# A proper way to access files on different machine using C#

Tags: c#, authentication, impersonation, filestream

I want to read files off of different windows machine on the same network, NOT part of the same domain though. (ASP.NET C# app)
Tried FileStream (can't authenticate), tried FileWebRequest (reverts to FileStream when file:/// is used), and impersonation ([support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#4)) Which says "impersonation failed" on my Vista.
Update: I've fixed "impersonation failed" issue. But still get "Access denied" from the other machine, even though i have "mirrored" user on both, so the question remains...
What is the right way to approach this task?

Comment: Why not write a simple service to serve the files? You can add authentication etc as required. IMHO, trying to directly access the file via a network share or something similar is just asking for things to go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but you asked for the *right* way, so... join the file server to the domain and grant ASP.NET's service account access to the share.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is proper approach, but it's the way I do it.  Assuming that you know a login for that computer, I P/Invoke a WNetConnection to the IPC$ object to authenticate with the machine, do my work, then do another P/Invoke to remove the connection to the IPC$.

Answer (score 0):

Try WebClient. You can use this to access a URI and I believe this includes using the 'file' protocol (or you could publish the remote file via HTTP).

You can use WebClient for a traditional download:

```
WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, string localFile)
```

Or return a stream:

```
WebClient.OpenRead(Uri address)
```

However your authentication issues may still remain. You can provide credentials in a standard Uri manner though may not be possible using the 'file' protocol.

I have never tried it, but I believe you can specify impersonation in the web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" username="[user]" password="[password]"/>
```

Though this sounds like a security risk, making your application take on the credentials of a network user rather than the anonymous user default.

More here anyway: [How To: Use Impersonation and Delegation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Map a drive e.g. "Z:" to the remote machine on the machine where your code is running.
The access the file using Z:...